# Render select option based on a API call in react

Tags: reactjs, antd

trying to make a API call , and based on that i want to show options in select field when the page load. I am storing the data from API call in a state and then i want to  displaying that data as options, i have tried a lot of things but nothing seems working. How can i achieve this in a clean way. Thanks for any kind of help.

**Code**

```
const AddNew = () =>{
const [displayData, setDisplayData] = useState();
const fetchResellerData = () =>{
  const data = request.fetchData();
  setDisplayData(data);
  console.log("testing in progress")
  console.log(data);
}
useEffect(() => {
  fetchResellerData();
}, [])
return (
  <form> 
   <Form.Item label="Status">
     {getFieldDecorator("status", {
         rules: [{
                  required: true,
                  message: "Please enter a valid status",
                },
              ],
            })(
              <Select>
                {displayData && Object.values(displayData.activity_status).map((status) => (
                  <Select.Option key={status} value={status}>
                    {status}
                  </Select.Option>
                ))}
              </Select>
            )}
    </Form.Item>
    

  </form>




)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const [displayData, setDisplayData] = useState({});   
 const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);

  <form>
            <Form.Item label="Status">

            <Select onChange={e=>{
                console.log(e.target.value);
                selected(e.target.value)
            }}>
        {displayData?.activity_status && Object.values(displayData?.activity_status).map((status) => (
            <Select.Option key={status} value={status}>
        {status}
            </Select.Option>
            ))}
            </Select>

            </Form.Item>


            </form>
```

or simply :

```
<select  defaultValue={2} onChange={e=>{
                console.log(e.target.value);
            }}>
        {[1,2,3] && Object.values([1,2,3]).map((status) => (
            <option key={status} value={status}>
        {status}
            </option>
            ))}
            </Select>
```

Comment: on page load displayData is undefined and in browser it giving an error like cannot read property of undefined due to "Object.values(displayData.activity_status)" this code.

Comment: displayData?.activity_status && Object.values(displayData?.activity_status)
                 
       what about it? I edited my answer.
displayData should have an initial value.